# Entity Framework 4.3.1 DBContext Connection

Tags: entity-framework-4

I'm trying to access the underlying Database and Connection object from DbContext in order to run some SQL "old style" in a library routine. This library routine uses DbContext as it can be called from many places. This worked in 4.1 however, with 4.3.1 I'm getting errors...

Here's the outline of the relevant code

```
using (testentities te = new testentities())
{
    var result = CallGeneric(te, some parameters);
}

public static Results CallGeneric(DbContext db, some parameters);
{
    var connection = (SqlConnection)db.Database.Connection;

    // do some stuff here

}
```

In EF 4.1 this worked and I was able to use the connection directly. I updated to EF 4.3.1 using NuGet and this no longer works. Any ideas on how to get to the underlying connection?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the "not longer works" part? I just tried getting the connection the way you do and it worked for me. Note that the connection I got was closed so in order to "do some stuff" I would need to open it. Also, there are SqlQuery and ExecuteSqlCommand methods on DbContext.Database class that might be useful for you.

Comment: Problem was my own little version of "DLL Hell". Turns out I needed to uninstall EF 4.1 *then* install EF 4.3.1. Once that was done, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to uninstall EF 4.1 and then re-install EF 4.3.1